# Why does "test" and "test" return "test" , 1 and 1 return 1 instead of True?

Tags: python, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Why does "test" and "test" return "test" or 1 and 1 return 1 instead of True?

```
>>> 'test' and True
True
>>> True and 1
1
>>> 0 and True
0
>>> 0 and False
0
>>> 'test' and True
True
>>> 'test' and False
False
>>> 0 and True
0
>>> 0 and False
0
>>> 1 and True
True
>>> 1 and False
False
>>> [2,3] and True
True
>>> [2,3] and False
False
```

why doesn't it return either True or False?

Comment: *Why does "test" and "test" return "test" or 1 and 1 return 1 instead of True?*  are you familiar with Comma `,` ? :)

Comment: because the only falsey value you are using is 0

Comment: Why should `"test" and "test"` return True? `and` is not a comparison operator...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations),

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> **(Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return to `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated argument.** This is sometimes useful, e.g., if `s` is a string that should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression `s or 'foo'` yields the desired value. Because `not` has to invent a value anyway, it does not bother to return a value of the same type as its argument, so e.g., `not 'foo'` yields False, not `''`.)

As stated in the documentation, if the first expression is Falsy in `x and y`, no matter what the value of the expression `y`, it will be returned, similarly if the expression `x` is truthy then the result of the expression `x` is returned.

That is why `"test" and "test"` gives you `test`. Try this,

```
>>> "test1" and "test2"
'test2'
>>> "" and "test2"
''
>>> "" or "test2"
'test2'
>>> "test1" or "test2"
'test1'
```

In `"test1" and "test2"` case, `test1` is evaluated and it turns out to be Truthy. So, the second expression also has to be evaluated and the result of that evaluation is returned as `test2`.

In the `"" and "test2"` case, since empty strings are Falsy, `and` need not have to check the second expression.

In `"" or "test2"`, since the empty strings are Falsy, `or` evaluates the next expression and returns that as the result. Hence, `test2`.

In `"test1" and "test2"`, since `test1` is Truthy, `or` need not have to evaluate the second expression and returns `test1`.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the documentation:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

```
x or y  if x is False, then y, else x   (1)
x and y if x is False, then x, else y   (2)
not x   if x is False, then True, else False    (3)
```

So it returns either `x` or `y` not `True` or `False` necessarily (except in the case of `not`).

Answer (score 1):

The rule is that it returns the last value whose truthiness it checked. The short-circuiting behavior of `and` and `or` means that that value will always have the same truthiness as the whole expression. The reason it isn't coerced to bool is largely because it doesn't need to be - and the current behavior is occasionally useful. For example, you can calculate the digit sum of any number like so:

```
 def digitsum(num):
    return num % 9 or 9
```

Which is equivalent to, but arguably more elegant than:

```
 def digitsum(num):
    mod = num % 9
    return mod if mod else 9
```

A more elaborate version of this was occasionally used as a ternary operator before python grew the conditional expression.

Answer (score 0):

`a or b` and `a and b` are evaluated like `a if a else b` and `b if a else a`, respectively.

This might seem strange at first, but its semantics are consistent with what you'd expect from `and` and `or`, if the results are interpreted as booleans. If you need the result to be a boolean, you can do `b = bool(x or y)`. When you use `or` or `and` in conditions (`if`, `while`, etc.) this is not needed.

Also, it is very handy. For example, you can use the `or` operator to provide default values. For example, `x = y or "default"` will assign to `x` the value of `y`, or `"default"`, if `y` is `None` (or any other value that evaluates to `False` as a boolean, like an empty list, empty string, etc.)

As to the question, *why* it is this way: I guess you'd have to ask the designers of Python.

Comment: wrt/ the "why" part: it's coherent with Python's definition of an object's truth value (as given by `bool(obj)`, and it's practically more useful than evaluating to a `bool`. If you want a boolean result, just pass the expression to `bool`, ie `bool(a and b)`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That's basically what I wrote in the paragraphs above, isn't it? :-)

Comment: err... well, actually, yes :oops:

Answer (score 0):

An `and` chain returns the first value which is equivalent to False or the last value if none of them is equivent to False:

```
a and b and c ... and z
```

returns:

`a` if a == False

`b` if a == True and b == False

`c` if a == True and b == True and c == False

...

`z` if all previous values are True